# Dynamic date in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

i am running the following command in a cmd:

Prog.exe -time Components_2016_04_19_11.ss

I want to write a batch file that will be run hourly and i need the date in the command to change accordingly - the date needs to be in the format above, and the last part of the date is the current hour minus 7 hours

So if the time now is 1/1/2016 20:43 the command will look like this

```
Prog.exe -time Components_2016_01_01_13.ss
```

i need help creating the appropriate batch file

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  If you're looking for a place to start, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36733204/1683264) might give you some ideas.

Comment: Have a look at `Get-Date -format`. It will allow you to create the string you want. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, questions resembling "Write this for me.  Here are my requirements." aren't well-received around here.  But this time, just to prevent any more unhelpful answers from being posted, I'll help you out with a solution.

Pure batch is really cumbersome with date math.  Compensating for midnight, month changes, leap years, etc. can be a nightmare.  It's much easier to use a different language -- one which has a proper Date object that will handle calendar quirks without having to hack around them.

Here's a PowerShell solution to your problem:

```perl
Prog.exe -time ("Components_{0}.ss" -f (Get-Date).addHours(-7).toString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH"))
```

That's it, just a one-liner.  If you require a batch script, you can employ the PowerShell helper to perform the date math heavy lifting.

```perl
@echo off & setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'powershell -noprofile "(Get-Date).addHours(-7).toString('yyyy_MM_dd_HH')"'
) do (
    Prog.exe -time Components_%%I.ss
)

goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-Date

Get-Date | Get-Member
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
$GBL = 0
do{
    Prog.exe
    Get-Date
    sleep 3600
}
while($GBL -lt 1)
```

`$GBL` it's a infinity variable for the loop. inside of the *do* execute the program and use the *sleep* for wait *3600 seconds* or *1 hour* for execute again. `Get-Date` it's for mark the date and time when the code it's executed.

I don't understand if you need this or something else.

You can modify the line of `Prog.exe` with the code you need.

If you answer me i can help you.

Have a good day (: